# install reCaptcha and white page

Tags: php, recaptcha

I've downloaded librecaptcha.php and made test.php:

```
<?php
require_once('recaptchalib.php');
$publickey = "MY_KEY"; // you got this from the signup page
echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
?>
```

But it shows white screen. Problem is in require_once(), because if I exit with echo before require_once() - it echoes to page, but if after require - doesn't echo.

File recaptchalib.php is in the same folder as the test.php

What it can be?

UPD 1:

I think, the problem is in `require_once('recaptchalib.php')`. No matter what code is after it, white screen will apear.
For example:

```
<?php
require_once('recaptchalib.php');
exit('test_after');
?>
```

This file return white screen. But this script works:

```
<?php
exit('test_before');
require_once('recaptchalib.php');
?>
```

So, the problem is in lib file itself. Path is correct, and I haven't modified the file.

**UPD2**:

So, I should to check recaptchalib.php file.
I've create `lib.php` file with such content:

```
<?php 
echo "lib"; 
?>
```

It've been opened in all browsers. But then I've added (copy-pasted) the content of recaptchalib.php before `echo "lib"`. So it looks like:

```
<?php
/* recaptchalib.php content*/
echo "lib";
?>
```

And I've seen blank screen in FF, `500 server internal error` in Chrome and `Remove server or file not found` on Opera.

**UPD3:**

recaptchalib.php began to work only when I've copied it's content **function-by-function** in a new file. (when I copied whole content - it hasn't work). I don't understand why??

Comment: I'm looking to your updates, and hmm... You're not alone confused in this situation. Are you using localhost or online server for this test? I have a lot of problems to test it on localhost but as you can see it works online (In fact, OS doesn't matter).

Comment: I'm using server (what hosting I do not know - I only have ftp access)

Comment: Yes, i see it. Everything replies on conditions from your screenshot. And I've already made a recaptcha for my site - it works fine. (but i've copy-pasted recaptchalib.php file in a new file). I think, problem was in some apache settings, because in php code it was fine.

Comment: Thanks for efforts and for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not problem in library!

**Your test script will work in Safari but will not work in Firefox!** (I don't know for rest of them because I use just these)

*Have you tried to check it in more than one browser?*

According to official documentation: [Using reCAPTCHA with PHP](http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/php.html) you have to put PHP code on HTML page.

> The **body tag is required** or the
>   CAPTCHA may not show on some browsers

So you have to create HTML page and it will work

```
  <html>
    <body>
      <!-- your HTML content -->

      <form method="post" action="submit_recaptcha.php">
        <?php
          require_once('recaptchalib.php');
          $publickey = "your_public_key"; // you got this from the signup page
          echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
        ?>
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>

      <!-- more of your HTML content -->
    </body>
  </html>
```

- Here's my [test](http://service-kl.com/code/recaptcha/) (works in all browsers)!
- Here's [your code](http://service-kl.com/code/recaptcha/index2.php) on my server (it doesn't work in FF, but works in Safari)

### Update:

Also double check is your domain on reCaptcha page same as one where you use your code.

Example:

[image]

[This is exact copy of my working example from server (removed Public Key)!](http://service-kl.com/code/recaptcha.zip) This is what I have here http://service-kl.com/code/recaptcha/

Give it a try, but before that, you have to replace public key in index.php with your own.

Comment: It is correct, but it doesn't matter. Problem is in require_once(). No matter what code is after it - white screen will be

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this later. I've tried my code on Firefox And Chrome. (But both your links work for me now - in Firefox)

Comment: I couldn't test it these few days, but' I've just tested. I've inserted `<?php ?>` code in body , and no result again.

Comment: Problem is when I requiring lib file. (it behaves like missed semicolon in this file). This file consists only of function - how it can block the script?

Comment: I admit it, very strange behavior. However, I still cant's see my 2nd example in FF. Maybe your library file was damaged (accidentally). Try to download fresh copy of library or just use [this one from my example](http://service-kl.com/code/recaptcha-php-1.11.zip). Also, if it doesn't work again, can you please post complete test script, one that requires lib.

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5, I don't like to write in comments so I'll add and `UPD2` and `UPD3` in my question - read it please.

Comment: @Innuendo, agree... you should edit your question. Just let people know about that posting comment.